# Google Drive Image View Limit

Tags: html

If I host images for my website on google drive, will they stop displaying after a certain number of views of the webpage? I can't find anything in google fair use but I know I've seen pages with broken image links that say things like "this file has been viewed too many times" or similar things.

Comment: Could you find exact error for the images that are not displayed? And append the message to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. Google decided a couple of years ago that it didn't want G Drive used in this way.

If you're looking for free website storage, AppEngine has a free tier that will probably suffice.

Comment: Oh, Awesome! Thanks for the info. I took a quick look and that should handle it.